# How to display events to Datagridview

Tags: c#

how do I show the event in my datagridview as if it were a Console.WriteLine?

I have an event that performs a revision of a network folder, which takes the name of all those files and tries to enter them in the database whenever it does not exist

but I want it to show me all that it shows me in writeline in the datagridview?

me writeline see :

prueba.txt
prueba2.txt

and i need see that in my datagridview it's possible?

"is to show an event not to query the database"

with your answer this happened

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a datagridview to your form, and call it `_eventsdataGridView` (don't add any columns)

Then you go like this in your class:

```
partial class EventsForm:Form{

    private DataTable _events = new DataTable();
```

Then like this in your form's constructor:

```
_events.Columns.Add("Event");
_eventsDataGridView.DataSource = _events;
```

Then like this instead of writeline:

```
_events.Rows.Add("file x was deleted");
```

Comment: It worked, you're great, thank you very much, I had to fix this line so that it would show me each file base_conexion.Close (); await Task.Delay (500);